# ¿Como puedo escribir en excel sin borrar lo ya escrito con c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, nuget

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad, es basicamente un punto de venta. El tema es que cada que se realiza una venta, se debe guardar el registro en un excel. estoy utilizando el paquete NuGet de SpreadsheetLight pero he notado que, cada que mi codigo escribe en el excel realmente lo sobreescribe, por lo que lo que había antes se borra.

Originalmente el exel tenia encabezados en las columnas para saber el contenido. Por eso el indice comienza en 2. Sin embargo, como ya mencione el codigo no escribe en el excel, realmente lo sobreescribe, por lo que lo que había antes se borra.

```
private void guardarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int indice = 2;
            SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in carritoDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 1,row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 2,row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 3,row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 4,row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 5,row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 6,row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 7,row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 8,row.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 9,row.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 10,row.Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 11,row.Cells[11].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 12,row.Cells[12].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 13,row.Cells[13].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 14,row.Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 15,row.Cells[15].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 16,row.Cells[16].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 17,row.Cells[17].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 18,row.Cells[18].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 19,row.Cells[19].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 20,row.Cells[20].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 21,row.Cells[21].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 22,row.Cells[22].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 23,row.Cells[23].Value.ToString());
                sl.SetCellValue(indice, 24,row.Cells[24].Value.ToString());
                indice++;
            }
            sl.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\alan\Escritorio\Registro.xlsx");
        }
```

Comment: ¿Quieres escribir la siguiente información al final de la ya guardada, escribir en otra hoja o que deseas?

Comment: Sí, lo primero. Quiero que la información que se escribe continúe a la que ya esta escrita

Comment: Entonces lo primero que debes hacer es abrir el archivo:  SLDocument sl = new SLDocument(<nombre de archivo>,<hoja excel>); Luego obtener el numero de filas de modo tal que empices a agregar en la fija siguiente., Tu código siempore sobreescribe el archivo.